# Dictionary item is present, but also showing as (null)?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a define like this:

```
#define MessageType @"MessageType"
```

This is used in the code with a NSDictionary called `message`:

```
NSLog(@"mesage...: %@", message);
NSLog(@"message type: %@", [message objectForKey:MessageType]);
```

This NSLog returns:

```
message...: {
1 = MessageType;
}
message type: (null)
```

I'm not sure why it returns it as (null) when it is obviously an object. This also doesn't work if I use my original code:

```
if (!message objectForKey:type) {
return;
}
```

So I need to check whether or not it's an object, but this code similarly isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your key is *1* and your object is *MessageType*.

You are checking otherway around!!! as `[message objectForKey:MessageType]`

Use `#define MessageType @"1"` or `[message objectForKey:@"1"];`

Comment: I'm not sure you're correct. My define is so I can use a standardised name for the MessageType key, then if i decide to change the string later on, i don't have to change it in every area of my code. And also if I use a string, I don't get told if i spell it wrong.

Comment: NSLog shows `key-Value pairs` isn't it? So in your case key is 1 and value is MessageType.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya **Anoop Vaidya is correct.**

Comment: @H2CO3: Here You come on my answer after a month :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Hmm, I see. Thanks. So how could i make a macro that I can then use as a key throughout my code?

Comment: I already mentioned as : #define MessageType @"1"

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Or possibly `#define MessageType @(1)` - we don't know if the key is a string, it may be an `NSNumber` as well. The description of `NSDictionary` is not completely informative.

Comment: But why would I want to define it as @"1"? That's just the value it returned, which was the correct value. I don't want it to return that every time. I just want to substitute a string for the key.

Comment: If you want a string then @"1" is fine.

Comment: Ah, I've discovered my mistake. In the area of the code where I set the dictionary, i put MessageType as the object, and 1 as the key.